# Spammer edited spam into question

Tags: discussion, flags

Wanted to bring this to mod attention as I assume the spammer missed out on being detected due to what happened.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65322916/revisions

OP posted a vague question, then edited it to include spam (I can only imagine they're trying to game their search engine rankings?)  I rolled back the edit as the fastest way to keep it out of any search indexes, and the question later got closed as 'needing clarity.'

Was that the right approach? Should I have rolled it back and 'flagged for moderator attention' or just flagged it as spam?

Comment: If the edit is made by the original poster (OP), then just flag as spam. If it was somehow edited into spam by someone other than the OP, then raise a custom moderator flag on the post. And yell "Eeeeeeeek!"